# MongoDB setIntersection passing array result recieved from aggregrate group

Tags: mongodb

> Hi
>
> I have a collections of CompanyDepartmentJobRole as below

```
CompanyID       Department      JobRoleID
------------------------------------------
1                  D1           J1
1                  D1           J2
1                  D1           J3
1                  D1           J4
1                  D2           J5
1                  D2           J1
```

I want to use setIntersection to find the Common JobRole in Various Departments.

I am able to group by and get Array of JobRoles in the department, but now after this i want to pass the result received to the setIntersection but dont know how to provide it.

Below is the query to group deparmentes and get JobRoles Array

```
db.CompanyDepartmentJobRole.aggregate( {$group : {
               _id : "$DepartmentID",
                JobRole: { $addToSet: "$JobRoleID" }

   } }   )
```

which returns result as

```
   D1        D2
  ----      ----
   J1        J5
   J2        J1
   J3       
   J4
```

But dont know how to pass this result to setIntersection , i am trying below query but not correct way

```
db.CompanyDepartmentJobRole.aggregate( {$group : {
               _id : "$DepartmentID",
                JobRole: { $addToSet: "$JobRoleID" }

   } },
   {'$project': {  
                  int:{$setIntersection:["$JobRole"]}
                 }
    })
```

> Could please anyone help.
>
> Thanks & Regards 
>   Ajay

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`setIntersection` is a projection operator and can't be used to find the intersection between arrays in two different documents. You can compute the set of `JobRoleID`s that are present in more than one department using the following aggregation query:

```
> db.so.aggregate([
    {$group: {_id: "$DepartmentID", JobRoleID: {$addToSet: "$JobRoleID"}}}, 
    {$unwind: "$JobRoleID"}, 
    {$group: {_id: "$JobRoleID", count: {$sum: 1}}}, 
    {$match: {count: {$gt: 1}}}
])
```

This starts off by computing the set of `JobRoleID`s present in a department, then it counts the number of times each `JobRoleID` occurs in the set of some department and only returns those which occur at least twice. If you want to restrict to specific departments, you can put in a $match stage at the beginning.

Comment: Hi Wdberkeley, The query is helpful but i need 1 more help

Comment: The query is helpful but i need 1 more help

The match condition mentioned by you contains count > 1 {$match: {count: {$gt: 1}}}

Can we get this "1" as dynamic result.count 
i.e. dynamic intersection department count

db.so.aggregate([
    {$group: {_id: "$DepartmentID", JobRoleID: {$addToSet: "$JobRoleID"}}}, 
    {$unwind: "$JobRoleID"}, 
    {$group: {_id: "$JobRoleID", count: {$sum: 1}}}, 
    {$match: {count: {$eq: departmentcount}}}
])

As i am new to MongoDB could you Please help me