# MongoDB Union and intersection in one call

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, mongodb-.net-driver

I want to be able to perform union and then intersection.

My Document strucuture:

```
{
    "_id" : 1,
    "items" : [ 
        52711, 
        201610, 
        273342, 
        279449, 
        511250
    ]
},
{
    "_id" : 2,
    "items" : [ 
        246421, 
        390200
    ]
}
```

This collection contains of thousands of Documents of above form. 
I want to perform Union on set of documents and then perform intersection on set returned from Union.

For example:

```
Set 1 contains Id: [1,2,3,4,5]
Set 2 Contains Id: [3,4,5,6,7,8]
Set 3 Contains Id: [12,14,15,16,17]
```

It should union all list items in set 1 and set 2 and set 3. Then perform Intersection on result of each set.

So far, I have got query that does union of list as following:

```
db.getCollection('Test').aggregate([
    { "$match": { "_id": { "$in": [1, 2, 3] } } },
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": 0,
            "data": { "$push": "$items" }
        }
    },
    {
        "$project": {
            "items": {
                "$reduce": {
                    "input": "$data",
                    "initialValue": [],
                    "in": { "$setUnion": ["$$value", "$$this"] }
                }
            }
        }
    }
])
```

Also I am doing all this in c# right now:

```
var group = new BsonDocument
                    {
                        { "_id", 0 },
                        {
                            "data", new BsonDocument {{"$push", "$items" } }

                        }
            };


            var project = new BsonDocument
            {
                {"items", new BsonDocument
                    {
                        { "$reduce", new BsonDocument
                            {
                                { "input", "$data"},
                                { "initialValue", new BsonArray()},
                                { "in", new BsonDocument { {"$setUnion", new BsonArray { "$$value", "$$this" }}}}
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            };



            var result = qaCollection.Aggregate()
                .Match(Builders<QAList>.Filter.In(x => x.Id, list))
                .Group(group)
                .Project(project)
                .FirstOrDefault();
```

This query takes some time since it could return large data. So it would really nice if i can pass multiple sets and it would union separate sets and intersect them so data is not to big to return.

thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

Answer based on the [answer given to question 24824361](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24916009/174843):

There is no function to automatically do an intersection in MongoDB across several different documents. However, it is possible to calculate the intersection by taking this approach:

1. note the number of documents you are intersecting
2. unwind the items array
3. count the occurrence of each item
4. *match only those items whose occurrence count matches the number of documents from step 1*

So for example if you are taking the intersection of items in 3 documents, then you unwind the items, count the number of times each item comes up, and finish with just the items which come up 3 times.

This will only work if each document's items array has no duplicates, of course.

So for example, if the source data is like this:

```js
db.test_unionintersection_stackoverflow_42686348.insert([
    { "_id" : 1,
    "items" : [ 10, 20, 30, 40, 50 ]},
    { "_id" : 2,
    "items" : [ 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80 ]},
    { "_id" : 3,
    "items" : [ 10, 40, 50, 60, 80 ]},
    { "_id" : 4,
    "items" : [ 20, 30, 40, 70, 80 ]}
])
```

Then if you want the intersection of documents 1,2,3 (for example), you want the result `[40, 50]`.

You can calculate it like this:

```js
var document_ids = [1, 2, 3];
var number_documents = document_ids.length;
db.test_unionintersection_stackoverflow_42686348.aggregate([
    { "$match": { "_id": { "$in": document_ids } } },
    { "$unwind": "$items"},
    { "$project" : { "_id" : 0, "item" : "$items"}},
    { "$group" : { _id: "$item", "count" : {$sum: 1}}},
    { "$match" : { "count" : number_documents}},
    { "$group" : { _id: "intersection", "items" : {$push: "$_id"}}},
]);
```

which gives you the result:

```json
{
    "_id" : "intersection",
    "items" : [ 
        50.0, 
        40.0
    ]
}
```